# Local microbreweries and craft beer in Tokyo

Tags: breweries, local

Are there local micro-breweries in Tokyo?

Are they serving local Japanese craft beer?

What are Japanese craft beer that one can find in Tokyo?

Answer (score 4):

There are many craft beer pubs in Tokyo.
But there is no craft beer brand made in Tokyo.
I recommend [Coedo Beer](http://www.coedobrewery.com/en/) from Kawagoe-city, Saitama-Pref.

Kawagoe is a traditional town near Tokyo. 
It takes 40 minutes by train from Shinjuku/Ikebykuro.
***Coedo*** has 4 flavors, "Kyara" (Golden Brown), "Ruri" (Blue), "Shiro" (White), "Shikkoku" (Black) and "Beniaka" (Red).
Especially, "Beniaka" is made from sweet potatoes in Kawagoe.
Kawagoe is famous for sweet potatoes.

And ***"Coedo"*** means "Little Edo".
"Edo" is the old name of Tokyo.
Kawagoe has still old Tokyo street.

Please come and drink up!

Answer (score 3):

You can find a lot of different **bars that sell** micro-brews in Tokyo. <strike>most</strike> **All** of the micro-breweries I know **of** are located outside of Tokyo. However, I can't definitely say "there are no micro-breweries in Tokyo" **as I am not omnipotent**.

**Again**, there are a ton of places to get micro-brews in Tokyo; here is a restaurant that I have frequented over the past years that serves Japanese micro-brews exclusively: [BanKan](http://ban-kan.com/).

BanKan has 14 taps of Japanese micro-brews and they rotate their offering frequently; whenever a keg runs out it is replaced with a new brew. A pint runs between 900 to 1400 yen and the current offering is [here](http://ban-kan.com/beer.html). Notice that the prefecture the brew comes from is listed as well.

Enjoy!

Comment: Your first paragraph is super confusing.

Comment: @im1dermike Noted and updated accordingly; see the bold/strike-through.

Answer (score 2):

On my 2nd trip to Tokyo, I found Popeye pub in a quaint part of the city @ Ryogoku: [Popeye Beer Club](http://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Restaurant_Review-g1066459-d1216476-Reviews-Popeye_Beer_ClubSumida_Tokyo_Tokyo_Prefecture_Kanto.html).

They have 70 taps and mostly from Japanese breweries.

Answer (score 2):

Another one is **Ryujin Shuzo Brewery** or **Ginko Kura Brewery**, [from Gunnma Prefecture](http://web.archive.org/web/20170727011231/https://www.mtcsake.com/beer/oze-ipa), not too far from the capital. **Oze no Yukidoke IPA** (that I tasted) seems to be their most popular product. I am disappointed for not finding any more precise references online now, but I advise to search the names in bold above on Google or Instagram (where I have my beer-also blog) to find some further pictures and information.